# Vba bitness migration - Type Mismatch on "-" operator

Tags: excel, vba, x86-64, type-mismatch, kernel32

We have recently begun migrating to Office 365. First day after migration, a user reported a problem with the following piece of VBA code, using the `kernel32.dll` library:

```
'@Esposed
'@Folder System.Text
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Byaval dst As Long, ByVal src As Long, ByVal length as Long) 

Private Const DEFAULT_CHARACTER_CAPACITY As Long = &H10
Pivate CurrentByteLength As Long
Private StringBuffer() As Byte

Private Sub Class_Initialize() 
    ReDim StringBuffer(0 To (DEFAULT_CHARACTER_CAPACITY * 2) - 1) 
                                                            '^ Type Mismatch!!!                             

End Sub
```

It turns out that our previous version of Office(2016) was 32bit, so we ended up with 2 migrations in one.

I have tried changing all the `Long` references to `LongPtr`, and converting all the constants using the `CLngPtr` function, with no success. Any idea on what is going on here?

Comment: Did you declare `DEFAULT_CHARACTER_CAPACITY` as `LongPtr`? You shouldn't.

Comment: @Rory I know I shouldn't, still I tried both Long and LongPtr for that one, no difference in results

Comment: I can't see how you would get a type mismatch on that line if it's declared as Long.

Comment: Check that there are no references marked as "MISSING:" by going to Tools > References in the VBA editor. Missing references sometimes cause strange error messages around built-in functions which have no obvious connection to the reference at all